# C# SHA512 to Base64, b64 string is too long

Tags: c#, .net, base64, sha, sha512

I'm working against an API which wants to have a SHA512 encrypted value, that has been turned into base64.

The thing is the API parameter has a 256 character limit, so  my base64 encoded SHA512 value cannot be longer than 256 characters, which they always end up being, my base64 is around 600 characters long.
I have no idea how base64 works, but to my understanding it cant be shorter because the SHA512 value is 512 bits which will always return the same length when encoding to base64? Or is there a way to get a shorter base64 value?

This is my SHA512 hashing method:

```
private byte[] SHA512Hash(string payload)
    {
        using (SHA512 shaHash = SHA512.Create())
        {
            byte[] sourceBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            byte[] hashBytes = shaHash.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);

            return hashBytes;
        }
    }
```

This is my signing and converting to base64:

```
        byte[] hashedPayload = SHA512Hash(payload);
        byte[] sign;
        string signature;

        using (RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
        {
            sign = rsa.SignData(hashedPayload, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
            
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(sign);
        }
```

The api im using do have a Java example, has i translated their java code correctly to C#?

```
String payload = "JSON_PAYLOAD_GOES_HERE";
byte[] msg_bytes = payload.getBytes("UTF-8"); MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512"); byte[] hash_value = md.digest(msg_bytes);

// getKeyPair is your own function that returns your key pair for signing-certificate
KeyPair keyPair = getKeyPair();

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
sig.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
sig.update(hash_value);
byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();
String signature = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes);
```

Comment: Does that part of the API you are using want your entire payload in 256 characters or just the signature?

Comment: the number of base64 characters is always 1.33 times the number of bytes you're encoding, because one base64 character encodes just 6 bits and 4 characters encode 4*6=24 bits which is equal to 3 bytes (3*8bits=24 bit).

Comment: @NataliaMuray only the signature! this is the api docu, https://developer.swish.nu/documentation/getting-started/swish-payout-api, am i misinterpreting something?

Comment: @jps oh okay i see, so there is no way to shorten the base64 then..

Comment: I don't think you need to manually hash your payload when `RSA.SignData` says that it's going to perform hashing itself. So you appear to be double hashing in your C# version.

Comment: @philipcode what exactly do you mean with *API parameter+? Is it a request parameter in the url ? But I think they need a request body and don't see any limits for parameters mentioned there.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ohhh i see, fixed that! didnt fix my issue though :(

Comment: Well, I'd also look up with `NONEwithRSA` actually means and compare that to the `SignData` call and arguments.

Comment: @jps oh sorry, i meant its a field in the request body, not a parameter :)